# convert date from MM/dd/yyyy to MMddyyyy only while downloading PDF format

Tags: java, date, servlets

I have a servlet code written as shown below,where I am passing the parameters through map function and I have to download the report in PDF format,where while downloading i have to add to my request.getparameter("param2") to request.getparameter("param1") with formatting date as MMddyyyy because it doesn't accept "/" while downloading the file.

Please try to help me with this query,Thank's in advance.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
 Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     map.put("Course_ID", request.getParameter("param1"));
     map.put("StartDate", dateFormat2.parse(request.getParameter("param2")));
     map.put("EndDate", dateFormat2.parse(request.getParameter("param3")));

     JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxmlFileName);
     JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, map, conn);
     JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp,
          "D:/ForReports/Downloads/" + request.getParameter("param1") +".pdf");

 System.out.println("Done exporting pdf format to view");
```

And in html parameters will be getting passed as shown,

```
<div class=" col-sm-3" class="form-group">
<br>
<p align="center" ><a  class="btn icon-btn btn-info"  ng-href="JasperServlet2?param1={{modelcourse}}&param2={{formatDate(startdate) |date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}&param3={{formatDate(enddate) |date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon btn-glyphicon glyphicon-print img-circle text-success"></span>&nbspClick Here To View report</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your date `MM/dd/yyyy` is a string Right?

Comment: yes,it is in a string format.

Comment: Have you tried to replace the `/` with Nothing using a string.replace Maybe it works

Comment: Tips: (a) You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes. (b) When rendering date-time values as text, stick with the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats, where possible, to make the work easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code may help :-

```
String date=request.getParameter("param1");
date=date.replaceAll("/", "");
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp,
      "D:/ForReports/Downloads/" + date +".pdf");
```

while other code will remain same.

Comment: this loses `Course_ID` (which was the `request.getParameter("param1")`) in the filename

Comment: Well... in the original code the value of "param1" was put in the filename, which was mapped to "Course_ID" earlier. In your answer this value is no longer present in the filename ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You use `SimpleDateFormat` to *parse* String to Date.
Why not use another `SimpleDateFormat` to *format* this Date to a String in the desired format?

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat3 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");
Date startDate = dateFormat2.parse(request.getParameter("param2");
String courseId = request.getParameter("param1");
String startDateText = dateFormat3.format(startDate);

Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("Course_ID", courseId);
map.put("StartDate", startDate));
map.put("EndDate", dateFormat2.parse(request.getParameter("param3")));

JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxmlFileName);
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, map, conn);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jp, "D:/ForReports/Downloads/" + courseId + startDateText +".pdf");

System.out.println("Done exporting pdf format to view");
```